# Full-text search for manpages and get the list of the name and descriptions from a console like apropos(1)

Tags: man, search, apropos

Is there any way to do a full-text search for manpages and get the list of the name and descriptions of relevant manpages from a console like `apropos(1)`?

You can full-text search the content of manpages with `man -K`. But there are three problems:

1. `man -K` does not show the title of the first result to console.
2. `man -K` shows only the title of manpages like this:

   `--Man-- next: ansible(1) [ view (return) | skip (Ctrl-D) | quit (Ctrl-C) ]`
3. `man -K` requires `Ctrl-D` to skip viewing the content of manpages.
   So you cannot use `yes(1)` to pass the response to `man -K`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's probably an easier way, but I find `man -K` can be combined with `-w` to print the paths of the files that contain the search terms, and you could combine that with `lexgrog` for instance to extract the whatis info:

```
$ man -Kws1 apropos | sort -u | xargs -rd '\n' lexgrog | perl -pe's/.*?: "(.*)"/$1/'
apropos - search the manual page names and descriptions
emacs - GNU project Emacs editor
groffer - display groff files and man pages on X and tty
info - read Info documents
lexgrog - parse header information in man pages
man - an interface to the system reference manuals
manpath - determine search path for manual pages
scanimage - scan an image
whatis - display one-line manual page descriptions
xman - Manual page display program for the X Window System
```

(here assuming GNU `xargs` for it's `-r` and `-d` options, though the latter is unlikely to be necessary)

You could turn it into a `full-apropos` script or function such as:

```
#! /bin/sh -
man -Kw "$@" |
  sort -u |
  xargs -rd '\n' lexgrog |
  perl -pe's/.*?: "(.*)"/$1/'
```

We're missing the man section information though. Since that is in the path of the file, we could add it back with something like:

```
#! /bin/sh -
man -Kw "$@" |
  sort -u |
  while IFS= read -r file; do
    section=${file%/*}
    section=${section##*/man}
    lexgrog -- "$file" |
      perl -spe's/.*?: "(.*)"/$1/; s/ - / ($s)$&/' -- "-s=$section"
  done
```

Comment: love this! But: Also highlights a bit how awkward this all is.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, re: your now deleted answer, note that `zsh` has a `zsh/db/gdbm` module allowing you to *tie* a zsh associative array with a gdbm db. That would only give you the name => summary mapping though as I don't think mandb indexes the contents of man pages.

Comment: yep, noticed that, and since I didn't really have a good solution to first fulltext-search the files, then map the filename to descriptions from the dbm, it made very little sense to keep that answer there.